# PHP Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to example.com:8010 (Connection refused) CentOS SELinux

Tags: php, centos, centos7, selinux

I'm trying to send a request to and get a response from a remote host. The actual host and port are not those in the title, they're just an example. I'm not sure if the issue is with the firewall or because of SELinux or something else. The same code works on my local Windows development machine, but when deployed on CentOS 7 (7.1 or something) with SELinux enabled, it gives me this error.

The relevant line of code is:

```
$s = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout);
```

Comment: have you tried to `telnet HOST PORT` to the destination?

Comment: @wodka Can you check the answer below, and comments? I think this is a virtual server. I didn't configure it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try from command line

```
telnet $host $port
```

if it works you will see at the end the message

```
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If it doesn't work (port blocked, proxy etc...), last line will be

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: $ telnet 93.184.216.34:8010
telnet: 93.184.216.34:8010: Name or service not known
93.184.216.34:8010: Unknown host

Comment: You must use space between host and port, not ":"

Comment: Connection refused

Comment: Then you may try ping and/or traceroute to see if server is reachable

Comment: When I try to telnet google I get Connection refused. When I ping google, I get a response. When I traceroute google, it goes up to 30 hops with * * *. I believe echo is not enabled for the target host so I can't ping it, but the traceroute is the same as google.

Comment: Can you try a different port , e.g. 80 , if it is a web server?
telnet  93.184.216.34 80 
If it works , it means that port 8010 is not open on the respective IP, or it is filtered by some firewall.

Comment: It was port 80 I tried with google. I've tested from my local development machine, and I know the port I'm trying to reach is open and responding. I think the outbound traffic may have been blocked very recently by a firewall network device on the network. I can't load google and probably other websites on links2. I'll contact the admin tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if SELinux is blocking your connection try temporarily disabling it by editing "/etc/selinux/config" setting "SELINUX=disabled".

If this allows the connection check if there is any SE Boolean that might block your connection: "getsebool -a" is the command.

Comment: I tried setting SELINUX=permissive but no change. Do I have to restart server?

Comment: SELINUX setting changes do normally not require a restart of any service.